# Pegasus Imaging PrintPro ActiveX control gives error when dropped on Delphi form

Tags: delphi, activex

I'm trying to use the Pegasus Imaging PrintPro v4 ActiveX control with Delphi 7 on a Win2K box. When I drop the ActiveX control on the form I get the extremely helpful error message

"Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 00000000."

and the component doesn't appear on the form.

There are a bunch of other Pegasus Imaging ActiveX controls installed and they work fine.

Any suggestions on where to start troubleshooting, I'm not very experienced with ActiveX control (I usually go for native VCL only).

Lachlan

Comment: have you tried adding the ActiveX to Excel? Does it work there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download the latest changes file it says that "Fixed an issue where the ActiveX DLL would not register on Windows 2000.".

You should try upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: Do you have a URL for that changes file? Is it a change list for v4 or v5?

Comment: It is from the v4 changes file.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the control is not configured properly.  You might not be able to "drop" it on the form, but might have to instantiate it manually.  The access violation you are experiencing is the attempt to get the value out of a pointer which is null.  Most likely the control has a required construction parameter which is not being set by the Delphi ActiveX component wrapper.